# how to rename the source columns to target column names while reading the data from BIG QUERY into PCollection in apache beam using python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

how to rename the source columns to target column names while reading the data from BIG QUERY  into PCollection in apache beam using python SDK

Comment: Can you detail more the process? Why you don't rename directly the column in your BigQuery query? is the column name is dynamic or known when the pipleline start? What's you language? Python or Java? What did you already write?

Comment: we are doing the poc where are implementing etl operations on dataflow. We have a requirement to read data from multiple tables in  Big Query and do some transformations and join these tables and write into GCS. I am unable to understand how to perform pandas like transformations in apache beam.

Comment: Pandas transformation are supported by dataflow now. And I never used dataflow in Python. I can't help on this :(

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through Beam [DataFrames API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/#using-dataframes), more specifically  [DataframeTransform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.dataframe.transforms.html#apache_beam.dataframe.transforms.DataframeTransform). There are still [Differences from standard Pandas](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/#differences_from_standard_pandas), make sure to be aware of them.

Let me know if you still need help with a specific example.

Comment: If you've got a minute, I'd love some help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70192304/dynamically-renaming-unknown-columns-with-apache-beam-in-python