# Dynamically renaming unknown columns with Apache Beam in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an incoming csv, with some unknown header.
I read in some mappings from a db into the pipeline.

I need to rename the headers using the mappings and end up with a schema that allows for null/none values everywhere.

I read in the csv as a dataframe, which is great, and then I hit a wall - I could easily do a df.rename(columns=headers), but headers is a pcollection, and apparently DataFrameTransform doesn't play nice with side inputs.

Anyone know how the heck I can get these two things to play nicely? Thanks

Comment: I've worked with unknown headers before and renaming columns based on some mapping, so I ask, wouldn't be easier to handle the header obtention and replacement outside of the pipeline? so you just provide the proper headers to each transform accordingly.